# Pass a parameter from inventory file to Ansible command?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run an Ansible command on a group listed in an inventory file,
the goal is to run a single command that will run all over the group instances and takes the ***"ansible_ssh_host"*** of each instance and use it as a parameter inside the command.

The command is:

```
ansible worker -i inventory -m command -a "start-worker.sh -h <ansible_ssh_host> spark://ec2-35-173-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077"
```

Example of the inventory file:

```
[master]
spark-master ansible_ssh_host=ec2-3-225-47-10.compute-1.amazonaws.com

[worker]
spark-worker-6 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-23-20.compute-1.amazonaws.com
spark-worker-7 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-52-6.compute-1.amazonaws.com
spark-worker-8 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-18-209.compute-1.amazonaws.com
spark-worker-9 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-54-147.compute-1.amazonaws.com
spark-worker-10 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-3-234.compute-1.amazonaws.com
spark-worker-11 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-52-205.compute-1.amazonaws.com
spark-worker-12 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-3-213.compute-1.amazonaws.com
spark-worker-13 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-34-199.compute-1.amazonaws.com
spark-worker-14 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-52-70.compute-1.amazonaws.com
spark-worker-15 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-52-72.compute-1.amazonaws.com
spark-worker-16 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-3-231.compute-1.amazonaws.com

[spark_cluster:children]
master
worker
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test it with the *debug* module first

```yaml
shell> ansible worker -i inventory -m debug -a "msg='start-worker.sh -h {{ ansible_ssh_host }}'"
spark-worker-6 | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "start-worker.sh -h ec2-23-20.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
}
spark-worker-7 | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "start-worker.sh -h ec2-52-6.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
}
spark-worker-8 | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "start-worker.sh -h ec2-18-209.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
}
...
```

---

Optionally, put the task into a playbook, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: worker
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "start-worker.sh -h {{ ansible_ssh_host }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml

PLAY [worker] ******************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [spark-worker-6] => 
  msg: start-worker.sh -h ec2-23-20.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ok: [spark-worker-7] => 
  msg: start-worker.sh -h ec2-52-6.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ok: [spark-worker-8] => 
  msg: start-worker.sh -h ec2-18-209.compute-1.amazonaws.com
...
```